# Unable to Map dataset Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have my first dataset in this format:

```
code_status       Product
5342            Home Product
4231            Appliance Product
5227            Home Product
6232            Furniture Product
7342            Electronic Product
```

We have 22 different code_status and 17 different Products.... that means one product may have multiple code_status...

Now, coming to other dataset, it is in this format:

```
unique_id     code_status
asd6767s       [6232,5598]
hfed44hh       [4534.6344.2337,2344]
dffd4f3g       [5343,6667,2563]
3hbh333y       [7454,2323,8855,2066]
```

In the second dataset, I need to create the product column...For example, if you will see the first row of the second dataset, it has [6232,5598], so here the first element of list ie. 6232 matches with Furniture product in first dataset (see the 4th row of 1st dataset) , so we should the value Furniture product here in the product column.... So, we have to mainly focus on first element of list in 2nd dataset and map with code_status of the first dataset to get the product column....

Can someone pls suggest me on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Use if need map first value of `code_status` value:

```
df2['product'] = df2['code_status'].str[0].map(df1.set_index('code_status')['Product'])
print (df2)
  unique_id               code_status            product
0  asd6767s              [6232, 5598]  Furniture Product
1  hfed44hh   [4534, 6344.2337, 2344]                NaN
2  dffd4f3g        [5343, 6667, 2563]                NaN
3  3hbh333y  [7454, 2323, 8855, 2066]                NaN
```

If need map all values:

```
s = df1.set_index('code_status')['Product']

df2['product'] = [[s[y] for y in x if y in s] for x in df2['code_status']]
print (df2)
  unique_id               code_status              product
0  asd6767s              [6232, 5598]  [Furniture Product]
1  hfed44hh   [4534, 6344.2337, 2344]                   []
2  dffd4f3g        [5343, 6667, 2563]                   []
3  3hbh333y  [7454, 2323, 8855, 2066]                   []
```

---

```
s = df1.set_index('code_status')['Product']

df2['product'] = [','.join(s[y] for y in x if y in s) for x in df2['code_status']]
print (df2)
  unique_id               code_status            product
0  asd6767s              [6232, 5598]  Furniture Product
1  hfed44hh   [4534, 6344.2337, 2344]                   
2  dffd4f3g        [5343, 6667, 2563]                   
3  3hbh333y  [7454, 2323, 8855, 2066]
```